# Solution for 'struct timespec' error in PyObjects C when creating a shared file .so

Tags: python, c, pyobject

I'm trying to create my own custom C function to run in a .py function making a shared library, but I keep getting error

my 100-print_python_list_info.c code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Python.h>


/**
 * print_python_list_info - is function prints info about python list
 * @p: object
 * Return: void nothing.
 */
void print_python_list_info(PyObject *p)
{
        long int size, index = 0, allocations;
        PyObject *obj;

        size = PyList_Size(p);
        allocations = ((PyListObject *)p)->allocated;

        printf("[*] Size of the Python List = %ld\n", size);
        printf("[*] Allocated = %ld\n", allocations);

        for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {       obj = PyList_GetItem(p, index);
                printf("Element %ld: %s\n", index, Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_name);
        }
}
```

i run this in my bash terminal:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -shared -Wl,-soname,PyList -o libPyList.so -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 100-print_python_list_info.c
```

output:

```bash
In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:118,
                 from 100-print_python_list_info.c:3:
/usr/include/python3.10/cpython/pytime.h:150:60: error: 'struct timespec' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
  150 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_FromTimespec(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timespec *ts);
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.10/cpython/pytime.h:155:56: error: 'struct timespec' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
  155 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_AsTimespec(_PyTime_t t, struct timespec *ts);
```

Comment: _"but I keep getting error"_ Actually, you're getting a warning, not an error, from an indirect include inside `Python.h`. It's only being promoted to an error because you passed `-Werror`. Either relax your warning flags or omit `-Werror`

Comment: @Brian61354270 Are you saying this warning should be ignored? Usually warnings are about problems in the code, so you should fix the cause.

Comment: it did really work i remove all and did this command instead ```gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,PyList -o libPyList.so -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 100-print_python_list_info.c```

Comment: But still i need to make it passing the warnings

Comment: What operating system are you building on? If you create a small test-program, build it with the same flags, and add the statement `printf("%ld\n", _POSIX_C_SOURCE);`, what does it print? Or do you get a build error about `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` missing?

Comment: Related CPython 3.10 issue: [#70040 - Compile error with pytime.h - struct timespec declared inside parameter list](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70040). According to the reporter there, this happens in CPython 3.10 when using `-std=c99`. Using `-std=gnu99` or `-std=c11` instead, or inserting `struct timespec;` before the include, resolves the warning.

Comment: @Brian61354270, Thank you alot it did really work, i tried both solutions and it worked one i used is inserting `struct timespec;` before the include, Thank you very much really helpful

Comment: @WaheedElhariri See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html for details why.